# Microsoft Bluetooth Mouse 3600 doesn't show on device list

Tags: mouse, bluetooth

I have a Microsoft Bluetooth Mouse 3600 with a Samsung NP300E5L-KF1BR laptop. It is currently running Ubuntu Xenial. I have TLP installed on Ubuntu also.

Since the day I installed Ubuntu on this laptop the mouse worked weirdly. It takes a while to the work with the laptop on system boot/system wake up and sometimes it disconnects, only working with a reboot.

Yesterday the device disconnected suddenly and unpaired and tried to pair it again. It no longer show on Bluetooth pair list on GUI or on `bluetoothctl`. The mouse works fine with my phone, and the phone also pairs fine with the laptop, so it must be something wrong between the mouse and the laptop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This link to the ArchWiki may be helpful](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Bluetooth#Thinkpad_Bluetooth_Laser_Mouse_problems)

I had similar issues with my thinkpad bluetooth mouse. It would pair with other devices and temporarily pair with my laptop but eventually unpair. The solution was as follows:

Edit/create the file `/etc/bluetooth/input.conf` and apply the following changes:

```
# Configuration file for the input service
# This section contains options which are not specific to any
# particular interface
[General]

# Set idle timeout (in minutes) before the connection will
# be disconnect (defaults to 0 for no timeout)
IdleTimeout=0

#Enable HID protocol handling in userspace input profile
#Defaults to false(hidp handled in hidp kernel module)
UserspaceHID=true
```

Comment: the `hcitool lescan` on last session in the wiki did the trick, yay